# Add depth to a Java Array Container

Tags: java, python, arrays, arraylist

I have a python program which returns a list of **shape** ***(1, 1, 1, N)***. I am calling this program in java, which first requires me to initialize a container(java array) of this shape. If the container is assigned correctly the python function can dump the values into the java array.
I want to know how to initialize such a container, I have little to no experience in Java but have to do this for some demonstration.

**Edits:**

Some more insights:

The array returned by python looks like this-

```
[[[[1,2,3,4,....N]]]]
```

I want a way to receive this array into a java array.

Comment: Are you indicating `how to declare and initialize 4 dimensional array in Java?`

Comment: See the edit for more details, regarding how the array is.

Answer (score 0):

I think ***shape (1, 1, 1, N)*** in python is not equivalent to `[[[[1,2,3,4,....N]]]]` in java,

Can you describe more about ***shape*** in python? Is it a tuple or is it a custom class defined?

Comment: the example that I have mentioned [[[[1,2,3,4,....N]]]] , this is what python shows me. This type of an array has to be received in Java.

Comment: I'm assuming it's a single array(innermost) embedded inside three arrays. One way of representing it is interms of List interface like the following `List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Can you give a proper example.

Comment: Construct innermost list(here it's `a`) first and then add it in the parent list like the following,
`List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
 List<List<Integer>> b = new ArrayList<>();
 b.add(a);
 List<List<List<Integer>>> c = new ArrayList<>();
 c.add(b);
 List<List<List<List<Integer>>>> shape = new ArrayList<>();
 shape.add(c);`

Now shape list will have the same representation as of [[[[1,2,3..]]]]. And, to access the innermost list, you have to do `shape.get(0).get(0).get(0)` which will have the `a` list content.

Try doing `System.out.println(shape);` to visualize the array